# Passing a list of functions to a method to be executed later with data supplied

Tags: scala, validation, recursion

I am trying to build a multi level `Validator` object that is fairly generic. The idea being you have levels of validations if Level 1 passes then you do Level 2, etc. but I am struggling with one specific area: creating a function call but not executing it until a later point.

Data:

```
case class FooData(alpha: String, beta: String) extends AllData
case class BarData(gamma: Int, delta: Int) extends AllData
```

ValidationError:

```
case class ValidationError(code: String, message: String)
```

Validator:

```
object Validator {

    def validate(validations: List[List[Validation]]): List[ValidationError] = {

        validations match {

            case head :: nil =>  // Execute the functions and get the results back 

            // Recursively work down the levels (below syntax may be incorrect)
            case head :: tail => validate(head) ... // if no errors then validate(tail) etc. 
            ...
        }

    }

}
```

Sample Validator:

```
object CorrectNameFormatValidator extends Validation {

    def validate(str: String): Seq[ValidationError] = {
        ... 
    }

}
```

How I wish to use it:

```
object App {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val fooData = FooData(alpha = "first", beta = "second")

        val levelOneValidations = List(
            CorrectNameFormatValidator(fooData.alpha), 
            CorrectNameFormatValidator(fooData.beta), 
            SomeOtherValidator(fooData.beta)
        )

        // I don't want these to execute as function calls here 
         val levelTwoValidations = List(
            SomeLevelTwoValidator (fooData.alpha), 
            SomeLevelTwoValidator(fooData.beta), 
            SomeOtherLevelValidator(fooData.beta),
            SomeOtherLevelValidator(fooData.alpha)
        )

        val validationLevels = List(levelOneValidations, levelTwoValidations)

        Validator.validate(validationLevels)

    }
}
```

Am I doing something really convoluted when I don't need to be or am I just missing a component?

Essentially I want to define when a function will be called and with which parameters but I don't want the call to happen until I say within the Validator. Is this something that's possible?

Comment: Could you please provide some more explanation ? I guess the text is convoluted

Comment: Make the list of `levelTwoValidations` a `def` instead of a `val`. Then the validations will be executed when referenced instead of when defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lazy val` or def when defining `levelOneValidation`, `levelTwoValidations` and `validationLevel`:

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val fooData = FooData(alpha = "first", beta = "second")

    lazy val levelOneValidations = List(
      CorrectNameFormatValidator(fooData.alpha),
      CorrectNameFormatValidator(fooData.beta),
      SomeOtherValidator(fooData.beta)
    )

    // I don't want these to execute as function calls here
    lazy val levelTwoValidations = List(
      SomeLevelTwoValidator (fooData.alpha),
      SomeLevelTwoValidator(fooData.beta),
      SomeOtherLevelValidator(fooData.beta),
      SomeOtherLevelValidator(fooData.alpha)
    )

    lazy val validationLevels = List(levelOneValidations, levelTwoValidations)

    Validator.validate(validationLevels)

  }
}
```

You also need to change `validate` method to get the validations `ByName` and not

`ByValue` using `: =>` :

```
object Validator {

  def validate(validations: => List[List[Validation]]): List[ValidationError] = {

    validations match {

      case head :: nil =>  // Execute the functions and get the results back

      // Recursively work down the levels (below syntax may be incorrect)
      case head :: tail => validate(head) ... // if no errors then validate(tail) etc.
    ...
    }

  }

}
```

Anyway, I think you can implement it differently by just using some OOP design patterns, like Chain of Responsibility.

Comment: The key parts were the `lazy val` and using `def` instead of `val` that did the trick. I looked into the Chain of Responsibility pattern and have refactored my code. My thanks to you @user3725190 and @jwvh